# Retrieve user object in a route that is not behind the firewall?

Tags: symfony

I am wondering if it is possible to retrieve the user object in a route that is not behind the firewall.

What I am trying to achieve is add a small container to my index page (not behind the firewall) that either shows a login form or a welcome message in case the user is already logged in. My security is set as:

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/secured
        form_login:
            login_path:                     login
            check_path:                     login_check
            csrf_provider:                  security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path:            secured_index_page
            always_use_default_target_path: false
        logout:
            path:                           /secured/logout
            invalidate_session:             true
            target:                         /logout-success  

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/secured, roles: ROLE_LOGGED_IN }
```

I guess invoking a secured route with an AJAX request would work but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's absolutely possible. In Symfony the user has an "authentication token" which contains his user details. By default, whenever a user connects to your site/application he will receive an [AnonymousToken](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AnonymousToken.html). When the user logs in successfully, he would usually receive a [UsernamePasswordToken](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.html) which contains his user entity object (the class you specify under `security.encoders` in the `security.yml` config file). This token is then used application-wide and you would have access to it on all pages no matter if they're under the firewall's protection or not.

To check if the user is authenticated you could use the following code:

```
// Inside a controller
class MyController {
    public function myAction() {
        if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
        }
    }
}
```

To check inside a twig template:

```
{% if app.user and is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    You are logged in and you're an administrator. You can remove is_granted() if you don't need to check for a specific role. This is just a full example.
{% else %}
   Please register.
{% endif %}
```

You can read more in the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#add-code-to-deny-access).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work though. In two browser tabs I have the index page and a secured page open. If I dump the app variable I see that tokenStorage.token is null on the index page and it is a UsernamePasswordToken instance on the secured page.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
{% if app.user %}
  welcome
{% else %}
  login
{% endif %}
```

in twig to check if user is logged in

Comment: app.user seems to be null on the non-secured page.